# Calculate minimum and maximum Ethernet (IEEE 802.3) frame size from frame format

Tags: computer-networks

[image]

According the frame format of Ethernet

Minimum Frame Size should be :

```
7Bytes + 1Bytes + 6Bytes + 6Bytes + 2Bytes + 46Bytes +4Bytes = 72Bytes
```

Maximum Frame Size should be :

```
 7Bytes + 1Bytes + 6Bytes+ 6Bytes + 2Bytes + 1500Bytes + 4Bytes = 1526Bytes
```

But it is said that the minimum frame size is $64Bytes$ while the maximum frame size is $1518 Bytes$.

How the frame sizes are calculated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preamble and SFD do not count towards the frame size since they are only part of the Ethernet *packet* (i.e., layer 1), not of the Ethernet *frame* (i.e., layer 2); see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure), for instance. Recall that Ethernet is not a pure layer 2 protocol but actually a mix of layers 1 and 2.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks